# Monaco Editor press Tab automatcally in choice snippet

Tags: monaco-editor

I tried choice snippets using [this](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example) example and replaced line 9 with this code:

```
insertText: {
   value: '"lodash": "${1|one,two,three|}"  $0'
}
```

After selecting one of the suggestions (one/two/three) by pressing Enter I want the cursor to jump to the end of the inserted string (where $0 is, highlighted on the screenshot below) automatically without pressing Tab. Is there any way to do that?

[image]